# Unable Install Squirrel.Windows

Tags: wpf, nuget, squirrel.windows

I'm trying to install squirrel.Windows for auto update of my application but getting this error

> 'SharpCompress' already has a dependency defined for 'NETStandard.Library'.

[image]

In using VS2012.
What should I do?

Comment: I'm guessing that you have a versioning mismatch. Sorry I cn't help but you might want to update all of your nugets and hopefully match them up.

Comment: maybe helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/7777319/3225

Comment: Try to use a newer version of Visual Studio.

Comment: What's the type of your app and targeted framework? (e.g. WPF App targeting .NET framework 4.7.2)

Comment: @kenny Sorry I did not notice that there are who answered in my query. I already fix  by updating accidentally my nugets. Can you move your comment into answer so i can accept us answer so other will know if they have same problem.

Comment: @Vic done, hopefully that helps somebody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment to try this suggestion moved to an answer on request of the OP.

" I'm guessing that you have a versioning mismatch. Sorry I cn't help but you might want to update all of your nugets and hopefully match them up."

Or

" maybe helpful stackoverflow.com/a/7777319/3225 "

### answer of this date copied here.

You should be able to force an exact version with brackets:

Full info on the formats you can use are on the NuGet site, here:

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/version-range-specification